# Very slow hover interactions in OpenLayers 3 with any browser except Chrome

Tags: openlayers-3

I have two styles of interactions, one highlights the feature, the second places a tooltop with the feature name. Commenting both out, they're very fast, leave either in, the map application slows in IE and Firefox (but not Chrome).

```
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    layers: [stationLayer],
    style: null // this is actually a style function but even as null it slows
}));

$(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    if(!dragging) {
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var feature = null;
        // this block directly below is the offending function, comment it out and it works fine
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(f, l) {
            if(f.get("type") === "station") {
                feature = f;
            }
        });
        // commenting out just below (getting the feature but doing nothing with it, still slow
        if(feature) {
            target.css("cursor", "pointer");
            $("#FeatureTooltip").html(feature.get("name"))
              .css({
                top: pixel[1]-10,
                left: pixel[0]+15
              }).show();
        } else {
            target.css("cursor", "");
            $("#FeatureTooltip").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

I mean this seems like an issue with OpenLayers-3 but I just wanted to be sure I wasn't overlooking something else here.

Oh yeah, there's roughly 600+ points. Which is a lot, but not unreasonably so I would think. Zooming-in to limit the features in view definitely helps. So I guess this is a # of features issue.

Comment: Do you have any other vector layers on the map than the layer with ~600 points?

Comment: What versions of the browsers are you experiencing this on? And operating systems?

Comment: I have a CA counties layer (from kml) with which I want no interaction (hence the check at forEachFeatureAtPixel to make sure it's a station feature). Right now that's it.

Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m, IE 11.0.9600.18059, FF 38.01 (just updated to 41.02, same issue). Win 7 Professional.

Comment: How about you choose an answer as correct and finish this thread?

Comment: I appreciate the help but there technically wasn't a solution, was there? I'd upvote the helpful advice if I could but I don't have enough reputation. Now if the common etiquette is to mark a solution anyways even if it isn't really (since this is more a bug that's out of my control), sure I'll do so, but, jesus, I'm clearly a new account, no need to be all passive aggressive about it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug and needs more investigation. You can track progress here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4232.

However, there is one thing you can do to make things faster: return a truthy value from `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` to stop checking for features once one was found:

```js
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(f) {
  if (f.get('type') == 'station') {
    return feature;
  }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'll definitely keep an eye on the bug tracking, helpful to know it's not just me.

Comment: For me this only happens when some larger polygons or lines are loaded (Firefox Linux). According to profiling it is the hit detection which probably struggles with lines/polys. The solution is to either disable mouse over in that case or use on click instead of mouse over.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue, solved a problem by setInterval, about this later
1) every mouse move to 1 pixel fires event, and you will have a quee of event till you stop moving, and the quee will run in calback function, and freezes
2) if you have an objects with difficult styles, all element shown in canvas will take time to calculate for if they hit the cursor

resolve:
 1. use setInterval
 2. check for pixels moved size from preview, if less than N, return
 3. for layers where multiple styles, try to simplify them by dividing into multiple ones, and let only one layer by interactive for cursor move

```
function mouseMove(evt) {
  clearTimeout(mm.sheduled);
  function squareDist(coord1, coord2) {
    var dx = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
    var dy = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
    return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  }

  if (mm.isActive === false) {
    map.unByKey(mm.listener);
    return;
  }

  //shedules FIFO, last pixel processed after 200msec last process
  const elapsed = (performance.now() - mm.finishTime);

  const pixel = evt.pixel;
  const distance = squareDist(mm.lastP, pixel);
  if (distance > 0) {
    mm.lastP = pixel;
    mm.finishTime = performance.now();
    mm.sheduled = setTimeout(function () {
      mouseMove(evt);
    }, MIN_ELAPSE_MSEC);
    return;
  } else if (elapsed < MIN_ELAPSE_MSEC || mm.working === true) {
    // console.log(`distance = ${distance} and elapsed = ${elapsed} mesc , it never should happen`);
    mm.sheduled = setTimeout(function () {
      mouseMove(evt);
    }, MIN_ELAPSE_MSEC);
    return;
  }

  //while multithreading is not working on browsers, this flag is unusable
  mm.working = true;
  let t = performance.now();
  //region drag map
  const vStyle = map.getViewport().style;
  vStyle.cursor = 'default';

  if (evt.dragging) {
    vStyle.cursor = 'grabbing';
  }//endregion
  else {
    //todo replace calback with cursor=wait,cursor=busy
    UtGeo.doInCallback(function () {
      checkPixel(pixel);
    });
  }
  mm.finishTime = performance.now();

  mm.working = false;
  console.log('mm finished', performance.now() - t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ahocevar's answer, a possible optimization for you is to utilize the select [interaction's `select` event](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.SelectEvent.html).

It appears that both the select interaction and your `mousemove` listener are both checking for hits on the same layers, doing double work. The select interaction will trigger `select` events whenever the set of selected features changes. You could listen to it, and show the popup whenever some feature is selected and hide it when not.

This should reduce the work by half, assuming that forEachFeatureAtPixel is what's hogging the system.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Updated the tooltip stuff to trigger on the interaction's selectEvent. Not a major speed difference in FF but good to streamline the code either way.

Comment: I found defining my own mousehover event to be far better than using a Select interaction, as I can check the evt.dragging property and prevent the call to forEachFeatureAtPixel() which is the bottleneck. As far as I can see the Select interaction calls forEachFeatureAtPixel()  with no filtering.